# PictureBox (Movement)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

Using code

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    slides += 1
    If slides <= 10 Then
        PictureBox1.Left += 50
    ElseIf slides >= 11 Then
        PictureBox1.Left -= 50
    Else
        slides = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

the picture box will slide/move to the right, then once it hits the right end of screen, itll go left (exactly what i want it to do... except...) but it keeps going left and goes past the left end of screen, what do i add to the code to make it go back to sliding right when it hits the left end of screen??
basically i want it to keep sliding back and forth from right to left to right and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never reset `slides` so it never enters the `<= 10` and thus never goes right again.  `slides` will just keep incrementing.  Here is one way you might modify your code to reset at an appropriate value of `slides`.

```
slides += 1
If slides <= 10 Then
    PictureBox1.Left += 50
ElseIf slides >= 11 Then
    PictureBox1.Left -= 50
    If slides = 20 Then slides = 0 ' Reset here so it goes back again.
Else
    slides = 0
End If
```

Comment: Do you mind explaining what the numbers do, i know that the picbox1.left += # is speed i think but i dont know what the slide = # does, It works when the 'If slides = 20' is that but it goes back to the right too soon, so i tried changing 20 to like 15 and then 25 and it stopped working all of a sudden.

Comment: @RDR It is using `slides` to control how many times it moves in each direction before switching. `slides` 1 to 10 move it to the right and `slides` 11 to 20 move it to the left.  If you change the 20 without changing the 10 and 11, you will get weird results because the two directions won't be equal. 50 is the number of pixels it moves with each tick so you could also modify that number to be equal to the width of the client area minus the width of the `PictureBox` divided by 10 (since 10 is the number of "slides" per direction).  `(ClientSize.Width - PictureBox1.Width)/10` might work.

Comment: I tried doing 1 to 9 and then 10 to 19 and then the picture just kept going left and never turned back to go right. But when I use your example code, it works fine, just the picture after hitting the right wall and going left, it stops in the **exact** middle and goes back right.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is using Mod which divides the 2 numbers and returns only the remainder. It's a bit crude but something along the lines of `(slides Mod 20) < 10` and `(slides Mod 20) > 11`